# Java Exception handle case

Tags: java, exception, throwable

```
public void backendExecute(Map appParams, BackendTaskMetaData metaData) throws Throwable {
    try {
        PeriodicTaskData ptd = (PeriodicTaskData) appParams.get(PeriodicTaskData.PARAM_KEY);
        String bizKey = ptd.getBusinessKey();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogServices.app.error("RPTPeriodicReportGenTask:"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With regards to the method above, if object pointed to is null, would come across as `NullPointerException`, I want to know if this exception would be caught or thrown to the invoker method? thanks

Comment: The first thing you should do is to run some code to test it.

Comment: got, thanks, the first time to ask, will try it myself next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Regard to above method, if object ptd is null, would come across nullpointexception,

Yes.

> i want to know this exception would be catch or throw it to invoker method?

The exception would be caught by the handler.  The handler will catch `Exception` and any exception that is descended from it.  `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException` which is (in turn) a subclass of `Exception`.  Therefore, it will be caught.

---

Now, if this may be just an illustrative example ... but it is a **bad idea** to:

- declare a method as `throws Throwable`, or
- catch `Exception` ... unless you are about to terminate the application.

Declaring a method as throwing `Throwable` makes it next to impossible for the caller to know what exceptions *could* be thrown.  Instead, the compiler will insist that the caller catches ... or propagates `Throwable`.

Catching `Exception` has the problem that you will catch *every* subtype of `Exception` ... including various unchecked exceptions that 1) you are not expecting, and 2) are probably symptoms of bugs that you cannot *safely* recover from.

Comment: now code change to following, add a method invoke before ptd.getBusinessKey, if method anotherMethod meet runtime exception (null pointer or classcast), the original method would catch this exception or throw it to caller?public void backendExecute(Map appParams, BackendTaskMetaData metaData) throws Throwable {
    try {
        PeriodicTaskData ptd = (PeriodicTaskData) appParams.get(PeriodicTaskData.PARAM_KEY);
        this.anotherMethod();
        String bizKey = ptd.getBusinessKey();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogServices.app.error("RPTPeriodicReportGenTask:"+ e.getMessage());
 }}

Comment: Same as before.  If the code throws and NPE, the handler will catch it.  The only possible difference is that the new call *might* throw an exception.  If that happened, you wouldn't *attempt* to call the `getBusinessKey` method.

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` is a parent class of `NullPointerException`, so it will catch it and not throw it to the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

As you are catching Exception class and NullPointerException is its subclass , exception will get catched not throwed.

Comment: I think you have a typo at the end of your answer. Did you mean to say that yes, it will catch the exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception e)
```

means that this will catch *any* exception (i.e. any subclass of `Exception`) thrown inside the preceding `try` block - which, yes, includes `NullPointerException`. Note that this is generally considered a bad practice, as you almost always will want to handle different sorts of exceptions in different ways, hence the need for multiple `catch` statements.

For instance, consider a method that could potentially throw an `IllegalAccessException` at compile time or a `NullPointerException` at runtime - it's difficult to imagine a situation where you'd want to handle them the same way, so you'll typically want to do something like this:

```
try {
    PeriodicTaskData ptd = (PeriodicTaskData) appParams.get(PeriodicTaskData.PARAM_KEY);
    String bizKey = ptd.getBusinessKey();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    //do something
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) { //for example... 
    //do something different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` is a subclass of `Exception` and thus will be catched, however it is recommended that you don't try and catch runtime exceptions. It is better to avoid them.

For example a null pointer could be avoided by doing the following:

```
if(ptd != null) {
    ptd.getBusinessKey();
} else {
    //Notify the user in some way or do something else.
}
```